# C# passing current object into another object?

Tags: c#

I am creating an object that has a constuctor like this...

```
public class BusinessLogic()
{

     public BusinessLogic()
      {

           BusinessLogicSubClass blsc = new BusinessLogicSubClass(and I want to pass in BusinessLogic here)
      }
}
```

I am doing this because I want BusinessLogicSubClass to call back to varying methods within BusinessLogic when it completes one method or another.  BusinessLogicSubClass also uses Constructor Injection in order for my Unit Tests to work with NMock2.

Any suggestions here would be helpful thank you in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
 public BusinessLogic()
  {
       BusinessLogicSubClass blsc = new BusinessLogicSubClass(this);
  }
```

An alternative to this (to address Jon Skeet's comments) would be to have a constructor, and an initializer, which uses the "this" pointer:

```
public class BusinessLogic 
{
    private BusinessLogicSubClass blsc = null;

    public BusinessLogic() {}

    public void Initialize()
    {
        blsc = new BusinessLogicSubClass(this);
    }
}

public class Implementor
{
    public void SomeFunction()
    {
        BusinessLogic bl = new BusinessLogic();
        bl.Initialize();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use `this` within a constructor. It's generally not a great idea though, as it means you've published a reference before the object has finished being constructed.

It's not really clear why you're creating a subclass within the class itself though - I suspect your inheritance hierarchy might not be ideal. Could you give some more details, so we might be able to recommend better design patterns?

Comment: I would agree with this.  If you are going to use this I would make sure it is the last statement.  The base class by Danny would be the way to go.

Comment: Re: hierarchy not ideal: True, but this may apply to some class that is outside the hierarchy too. I'm guessing he may not actually mean "subclass" here.

Answer (score 1):

Can you used lazy instantiation on a property to delay the instantiation of BusinessLogicSubClass for when you need it and when BusinessLogic has completed construction? I think this would be a better design. E.g.

```
public class BusinessLogic {

    private BusinessLogicSubClass mChild;

    public BusinessLogic() {
    }

    public BusinessLogicSubClass Child {
        get {
            return mChild ?? (mChild = new BusinessLogicSubClass(this));
        }
    }

    public class BusinessLogicSubClass {
        public BusinessLogicSubClass(BusinessLogic parent) {
        }
    }
}
```

Use lazy instantiation to prevent passing `this` in the original constructor which is not a good idea for a not properly constructed object - although could be ok depending on what else is going on.

Answer (score 0):

So, do you want something like this:

```
public class BusinessTest
{
    private BusinessSubTest aSub;

    public BusinessTest()
    {
        aSub = new BusinessSubTest(this);
    }

}

public class BusinessSubTest
{
    public BusinessSubTest(BusinessTest aTest)
    {

    }    
}
```

Or am I misreading the question?

Answer (score 0):

how about "this", e.g.

```
public BusinessLogic()
{
    BusinesLogicSubClass blsc = new BusinessLogicSubClass(this);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about using a static method that constructs BusinessLogic and then constructs BusinesLogicSubClass passing the BusinessLogic instance into its constuctor.

Then use a property on the BusinessLogic instance to pass in BusinesLogicSubClass?

For example...

```
public class BusinessLogic
{
    private BusinessLogicSubClass subClass;

    private BusinessLogic()
    {
    }

    public static BusinessLogic CreateBusinessLogic()
    {
        BusinessLogic bl = new BusinessLogic();
        BusinessLogicSubClass blsc = new BusinessLogicSubClass(bl);

        bl.subClass = blsc;
        return bl;
    }
}
```

So the constructor is marked private so the only way to construct the object is via a call to the static method like this...

```
BusinessLogic bl = BusinessLogic.CreateBusinessLogic();
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears as though this was working.  I thought it was thowing an error for me.

Using Initialize instead of the constructor sounds pretty good and I think I will switch over to it.

Lazy instantiation looks pretty good but this class is for now the class that starts this app.  Maybe I need something more here to make this work?(Like something that calls the property?  I suppose I have a caller that could lazy instantiate this.. I'll have to think on this more.

I must say from Si Keep I am out of my realm to really understand the answer.  Maybe an example would help me to understand.

Thanks for the help.  I'll be trying later to register since this first try out of Stack Overflow seemed to work pretty well.
:)

Comment: Hi, sorry for not being clear I was in a rush at the time. I have added an example. Si.

Answer (score -1):

I am guess you want to pass it the class you are just creating.  Use the this keyword, which passes the current object.

```
public class BusinessLogic()
{

     public BusinessLogic()
      {

           BusinessLogicSubClass blsc = new BusinessLogicSubClass(this)
      }
}
```